# Ubuntu 11.10 OpenVPN config

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to setup a vpn server with an old box I have at my office. I only have a single ethernet port and saw on reddit that it was possible to use only one to create a vpn server.

The problem is that my router is set at 192.168.1.1 and in `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` I have `server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0`. It automatically sets the TUN interface to 192.168.1.1 and I think thats is conflicting with the router IP. Is there a way around that by possibly setting that ip to be different?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this VPN setup? This seems a bit strange for a business environment.

Comment: I don't think it's that odd: I've seen it a number of times with very small businesses, where someone would like remote access to work files. One SMB consultant I know actually flashes Linksys routers for these business with something like DDWRT so it can run OpenVPN for this sort of access.

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/openvpn/server.conf and change the line to `server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0` then.  You will need to add some static routes on the router, in that case, so that machines inside your network will know to use the openvpn server to find the VPN clients.

You can also set up openvpn to use TAP instead of TUN.  Here are some instructions:

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html

In this case, the openvpn clients will be bridged to your internal LAN, and will use your routers DHCP server to get addresses.  In that case, your networks won't conflict, as it will all appear to be on the LAN.